# All catagories set to noindex,follow

Tags: magento-2.3

all thnx for the help in advance.

Since today all our category pages are set to:
`meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,FOLLOW"`

But, i'm not the developer, I can just use the "backend" magento menu. Is there any way that, I could have changed something that caused this?

Since the `robot.txt` file is only available in the code or in google SC?

hope you can help me out!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from below admin configuration

> Content > Design > Configuration > edit Global (or per store) > Search
>   engine robots > Default Robots and Select any one from below
>
> INDEX, FOLLOW
>
> NOINDEX, FOLLOW
>
> INDEX, NOFOLLOW
>
> NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW

Comment: Yes, the thing is I have not done this. But has changed anyway. Try to solve this with above didnt work.

Comment: This has been solved. I treid to get sorting by price working. Sice it had to take special price in account, I changed that and it messed with the robot file somehow